# Monitoring C pointer by using KVO

Tags: c++, objective-c, pointers, key-value-observing

I am trying to create a function in Objective-C for monitoring a pointer declared on my C/C++ side of code by using KVO.  Is there a way to do this?

To elaborate.  I have a C object pointer. I pass that pointer as `void*` through my bridge function down to Objective-C side of the code.

Is it possible to use the pass-down `void*` to set up KVO and notify via:

`-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *) keyPath of Object:...`

when the C object pointer is modified by C side of code?

Answer (score 0):

KVO, with its ability to just observe a property and automatically get notifications every time it changes, seems like magic, but really all it is is Apple automatically changing your property's setter from this:

```
- (void)setFoo:(Foo *)newFoo {
    self.foo = newFoo;
}
```

into this:

```
- (void)setFoo:(Foo *)newFoo {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"foo"];
    self.foo = newFoo;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"foo"];
}
```

The `will` and `didChangeValueForKey:` methods are what cause the KVO system to check for observers for the property, and notify them if there are any. The automatic substitution of the setter is done by taking advantage of the extremely dynamic nature of Objective-C, which makes it relatively simple to patch methods and alter them at runtime (this is, incidentally, why the `dynamic` keyword is needed to implement KVO properties in Swift). Of course, these dynamic features do not exist in C or C++.

What you will need to do, then, is to have your C code define two callbacks; one which the C code will call before changing the value, and another which it will call afterwards. Once you've got this set up, have the Objective-C side register these callbacks somewhere in your setup process, and have the callbacks call the `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` methods. Once you've done this, you should be able to observe the property using the normal KVO methods.